# Apply site theme or design with PnP Provisioning

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I would like to replicate the option available under "Settings - Site Design - Chose Site design - Apply to site within a PnP site provisioning template. This is a newly created subsite under an existing site collection.

Is this possible? I tried with powershell too, but looks like that the `Set-PnPWebTheme` command require tenant admin (?) permissions. Why isn't site collection admin (or even sharepoint admin) permissions not enough?

Edit:
I tested, and Change the look - Theme would do it also. Also tested, change the site theme requires tenant admin rights.

Comment: Do you want to apply site design or site theme (change the look > theme) , sorry a bit confused ? The naming convention is bit confusing as well :)

Comment: Updated question. Site design or theme, both will do. My site design contains the theme only.